# Orchard CMS with MVC Web App

Tags: asp.net-mvc, orchardcms

I need to build a simple Asp.Net MVC web app with a couple of forms / grids pages.  This app will accessible through a public-facing website which is using Orchard.  I'd like the app to run on top of Orchard as well, preferably within the same Orchard "site", to make use of the themeing and possibly some content management.

What I've tried so far is to make the entire app a module that I use in the public-facing Orchard site.  This is sort of working, but changes I make to the module after it's added aren't being reflected, and none of my breakpoints are hit in the module.

Am I going down the right road with the module, or is there a better way to get this level of customization while still being able to use my public-facing site's theming and content management?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Things to check:

- You need a manifest in your module's folder
- The feature needs to be enabled in Orchard
- You need routes to be defined in the module rather than in global.asax (look at any routes.cs)

But this is definitely the way to go.